# errors micronaut on Cloud Run fully managed -- setsockopt , RoutingInBoundHandler

Tags: micronaut, google-cloud-run

Seeing this with my own apps, as well as when I deploy the [micronaut-gcp hello-world example](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gcp/tree/master/examples/hello-world-cloud-run) to Cloud Run (fully managed)

When the service starts up, I see warnings from gVisor sandbox:

```
Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x41,0x6,0x6,0x3ecbfbbfdb1c,0x4,0x3a). Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.
```

and, later, I see errors from RoutingInBoundHandler:

```
[36m18:59:02.803[0;39m [1;30m[nioEventLoopGroup-1-4][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [35mi.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler[0;39m - Micronaut Server Error - No request state present. Cause: Connection reset by peer


java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:247)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1147)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825
```

I can hit the hello-world controller successfully, even after the above error messages.

When I run locally, or deploy the same containers to my local k8s cluster, I don't see the error logs from RoutingInBoundHandler.

I assume the messages above are related to the sandboxed environment... Are there micronaut/netty configuration settings I should be using?

Comment: The `setsockopt()` call is either trying to enable or disable the socket to send broadcast data. Broadcast is not supported in Google Cloud. However, that action is not related to the `Connection reset by peer`. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications Split your question into two questions.

Comment: Can you try to set this property `micronaut.security.oauth2.state.enabled` to `false`. If it works I could answer and explain you!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Do you think the `micronaut.security.oauth2.state.enabled` setting will affect the app mentioned (https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gcp/tree/master/examples/hello-world-cloud-run)?

Comment: I absolutely don't know. I'm on my cellphone and I hadn't have the chance to test by myself. When I could (I hope tomorrow), I will answer more clearly!

Comment: I set `micronaut.security.oauth2.state.enabled` to `false`, but that didn't appear to have an effect

Comment: I also have tested on my side. No effect. In any case, it doesn't affect the service behavior but it noises your logs. There is also several other call that are rejected by GVisor. I don't know if Micronaut team work to be better integrated to GVisor sandbox...